# Options for FTPing files from batch script without storing password in plain text

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, password-protection

I would like to run a scheduled batch script that will upload a file to an ftp directory, however I would like to avoid writing the password in the batch file. If there are any, what are my options?

Comment: If you want to run it unattended you'll have to store the password *somewhere*.

Comment: @joey thanks, to be honest I'm not expecting there to be an easy answer but you never know.

Comment: @AdamSweeney that's not a bad idea, why didn't you make it an answer?

Comment: You could schedule the task to run as userX then store the password in a file that only userX has permissions to read

Comment: May ask the person who voted to close for their reason please? I genuinely can't see what is wrong with this question but I would be happy to hear how I could improve it.

Comment: @AlexK. another good comment that probably should be an answer.

Comment: try looking at this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821762
it seems to show you how to encrypt/decrypt via VB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is going to stay on the same machine, you could store it as an environment variable. Then call it within the batch file

Answer (score 2):

You could schedule the task to run as userX then store the password in a file or a registry key that only userX has permissions to read. The windows scheduler can store the account password alongside the job.